# Express Session Different Expiration

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, cookies

I have the following code to create sessions in Express.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'randomstring',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 60000 * 60 /* 1 hour */
    }
}));
```

I mainly use this to store session data in Passport.js. Currently after 1 hour users get automatically logged out. Or the session ends and users get logged out.

Is there an easy way to store more data in the session and have different expiration dates for different information? So say I want the Passport.js (`req.session.passport.user`) session data to have an expiration of 1 hour. And I want another piece of data say for example (`req.session.myDataA`) to have an expiration of 30 days. And I want another piece of data (`req.session.myDataB`) to have no expiration and stay active forever.

Is there an easy way to achieve this behavior in Express Sessions?

Comment: Any reason for not using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu Local Storage has it's drawbacks in terms of storing session type data. Cookies get sent along with every request to a specific domain. Local Storage doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cookies and set different expirations on different cookie names.  So you can have multiple cookies that would hold data and each one would have a specific expiration.

That being said, I would say that both sessions and cookies wouldn't be the correct solution to your problem.  I would keep your sessions lean and store the data in a database.  Considering you're using sessions, you could use Redis and store data with expirations.  You could assign the key in Redis to your session.  For example:

```
req.session.myDataA = 'user_id:myDataA'
req.session.myDataB = 'user_id:myDataB'
```

When you set your data in Redis, you can use the key `user_id:myDataA` and set it to expire.

```
// Will expire in 1 hour
SET user_id:myDataA "your data"
EXPIRE user_id:myDataA 3600
```

While the key will still be in session, you can check if the value is `null` or has the data you're expecting.

I know this perhaps sounds a little more complicated, but even as a good practice with sessions, you really don't want to be storing a lot of data, beyond keys of reference as it becomes very difficult to manage.

If you're using MongoDB, you could also set documents to expire.  However, if you're not using either, Redis would generally be the easiest to setup and acts a good session store.

Edit:

As commented below, instead of expiring the sessions which you can't at different time frames, is to just set a field in your data with expiration time. Then when you get that data, check if it's passed expiration (i.e., 1hr, 30days, etc.).

Comment: I mean right now I'm only storing the user id in the session. But Passport.js handles most of that. I think this answer is slightly more complicated than what I'm looking for. If possible I would like to integrate with my existing Passport.js implementation and try to keep it as high level as possible.

Comment: Probably the simplest solution, instead of expiring the sessions which you can't at different time frames, is to just set a field in your data with expiration time.  Then when you get that data, check if it's passed expiration (i.e., 1hr, 30days, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You could set the maxAge of session in another middleware

code:

```
// after session and passport middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user) { // some condition
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
    } else if (req.session.myData) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 60

    }
    // another condition

    // save the session
    req.session.save()

    // add next at the end of middleware 
    // so it can pas data edited to another middleware
    next()
})
```

Comment: Well if I want to store user and myData in session that won’t work. I want to store multiple things in the session and have different expiration’s for each.

Comment: Forgive me did you mean 'things' in session that have different expirations? Should they be expired when the session is expired?

Comment: Yes. So I have multiple things in the session. Each with a different expiration time. The session it self I’d like to never expire. Just the things within it have different expiration times.

Comment: it is working. it is able to set the different expiration times for different session . in my case I am using a Redis database to store the session data and this piece of code works well.